# Can't install new packages in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, apt

I would like to install ffmpeg. My normal procedure to install this package would be:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

However when I run `sudo apt update` I get some errors including:

```
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 277A7293F59E4889 MiKTeX Packager <packager@miktex.org>
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7A3A762FAFD4A51F
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/systems/win32/miktex/setup/deb focal InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 277A7293F59E4889 MiKTeX Packager <packager@miktex.org>
```

And then when I run `sudo apt install ffmpeg` and selecting `Y` to some options, I get:

```
(base) robbie@ro-rmallett-l1:~$ sudo apt install ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libavdevice58 libdc1394-25 libopenal-data libopenal1 libsdl2-2.0-0
Suggested packages:
  ffmpeg-doc libportaudio2
The following NEW packages will be installed
  ffmpeg libavdevice58 libdc1394-25 libopenal-data libopenal1 libsdl2-2.0-0
0 to upgrade, 6 to newly install, 0 to remove and 19 not to upgrade.
Need to get 3,046 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,642 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libdc1394-25 libopenal-data libopenal1 libsdl2-2.0-0 libavdevice58 ffmpeg
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] Y
Err:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 libdc1394-25 amd64 2.2.6-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Ign:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 libopenal-data all 1:1.19.1-2
Err:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 libopenal1 amd64 1:1.19.1-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Ign:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libsdl2-2.0-0 amd64 2.0.14+dfsg2-3ubuntu0.1
Ign:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 libavdevice58 amd64 7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
Ign:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 ffmpeg amd64 7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
Err:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 libopenal-data all 1:1.19.1-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libsdl2-2.0-0 amd64 2.0.14+dfsg2-3ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 libavdevice58 amd64 7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 ffmpeg amd64 7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libd/libdc1394/libdc1394-25_2.2.6-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openal-soft/libopenal-data_1.19.1-2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openal-soft/libopenal1_1.19.1-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libsdl2/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.14%2bdfsg2-3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavdevice58_4.4.2-0ubuntu0.21.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_4.4.2-0ubuntu0.21.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

When I use `--fix-missing` after either call it doesn't help. To be honest I can't understand the error messages. I'm running Ubuntu 21.10. What should I do? I can't seem to install any new packages with apt-get.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on  https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

First of all - check your internet connection. I had the same issue on Debian, solution to this was lost packets from redirecting port on my router. Maybe you have some bad firewall rules.

Comment: This has been happening to me for a while on several different internet connections. I'm not sure what "lost packets from redirecting port" would mean?

Comment: Forget about that, i've done some looking and it seems that you're running an old instance of Ubuntu that wouldn't get any updates.. [Check how to update](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)